# Что это за разъём?

Tags: ноутбук, samsung

Разбирал ноут samsung n300u1a и заметил интересный порт (80 port) рядом с оперативкой. Что это может быть?
В интернете ничего не нашёл... 10 пинов. Похож на SATA разъём ноутбучный. Мне кажется, что это для диагностики порт.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно смотреть схему на вашу платформу. Может и диагностический...

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это вопрос, хоть и кажется интересным, но он совсем про железки. ru.stackoverflow про программную часть, не про железную

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Даташит](https://zremcom.ru/scheme/scheme-samsung/file/1146-sheme-samsung-np-rv420520720scala2-rrev01) (схема) для мат.платы в вопросе.

Это стандартный диагностический разъём **80 port debug**.

Во время теста POST BIOS генерирует коды прохождения (POST-коды) и направляет их в порт ввода/вывода 80h. Если процедура POST завершилась неудачно, последний сгенерированный POST-код остается в порту 80h. Этот код можно использовать для определения причины ошибки.

Как правило, на ноутбуках не размещают числовой или звуковой индикатор ошибки. В таком случае используют [POST-плату(карту)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_Card). Она декодирует данные порта и отображает их на светодиодном дисплее. Её необходимо устанавливать в этот разъем.